# send email in Background with Company-email , not with Gmail-Email

Tags: android, email, pdf, background, attachment

please help me
how can i send email in Background without Gmail-Emai.
i want to send email with Company-Email.
I need to Help
thank you very much

my Code:

```
  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("*/*");


            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{Reparatur_Email});
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, emailBetreff);
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , emailText);

            File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            String pathToMyAttachedFile = Speichern_Path+ Pdfname;
            File file = new File(root, pathToMyAttachedFile);
            if (!file.exists() || !file.canRead()) {
                return;
            }
            
           Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.example.android.fileprovider",file);
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

            context.grantUriPermission(getActivity().getPackageName(),uri,Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);


            context.revokeUriPermission(uri,Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);


            List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos_List = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(i,PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

            for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo:resolveInfos_List){
                String Package_Name= resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                context.grantUriPermission(Package_Name,uri,Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

            }

            try {

                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Email senden"));

            }
            catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
              
            }
```

please help me,how can i send email in Background without Gmail-Emai.
i want to send email with Company-Email.
I need to Help
thank you very much

MY send Gmail_Background Code:

```
BackgroundMail bm = new BackgroundMail(this);

bm.setSendingMessage("Email wird an Abrechnung versendet");

bm.setGmailUserName(Commen.Email_adresse);

bm.setGmailPassword(Commen.Email_Password);

bm.setMailTo(Commen.Email_Abrechnung);

bm.setFormSubject(emailBetreff);

if (filePath.exists()) {

    bm.addAttachment(Pdf_Path);

} else {

    bm.setType("text/plain");

    emailText = "Text";

}

bm.setFormBody(emailText);

bm.send();
```

I want send email in Background with m.nebo@wind.energy

Thank you very much

Comment: Have your app securely communicate with your Web service, and have the Web service send the email. The only way to send email directly from your app requires you to embed the email server, username, *and password* in the app, and those credentials can be extracted and used by spammers.

Comment: I want to send email with company_email and not with gmail. please help me

Comment: `BackgroundMail bm = new BackgroundMail(this);

bm.setSendingMessage("Email wird an Abrechnung versendet");

bm.setGmailUserName(Commen.Email_adresse);

bm.setGmailPassword(Commen.Email_Password);

bm.setMailTo(Commen.Email_Abrechnung);

bm.setFormSubject(emailBetreff);

if (filePath.exists()) {
    
    bm.addAttachment(Pdf_Path);
    
} else {
    
    bm.setType("text/plain");
    
    emailText = "Text";
    
}

bm.setFormBody(emailText);

bm.send();
`